# How would I go about writing pseudocode for finding a sink in an adjacency matrix?

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, pseudocode

Like what would the pseudocode even look like? I know what a sink is and think I could tell you the process identify one. But how do I represent the matrix and its rows and columns? Thanks.

Comment: Are you asking how we represent matrices in code?

Comment: That would help! Like I would move through a row while the number I'm at is a one, and stop if it's zero then proceed to the next row. How to I write that in code?

Comment: There's a lot of different ways, depending on the language you're using. Which language are you thinking about? Or should we just go with whatever we are most comfortable with?

Comment: We use java, but this can be any pseudocode. Working on hw and after I write this I need to analyze the worst case running time. Thanks for looking into my question.

Answer (score 0):

In Java you could declare a 2d matrix of boolean values like this:

```
final int ROWS = 8;
final int COLS = 8;
boolean matrix[][] = new boolean[ROWS][COLS];
```

Then you fill the matrix with some data:

```
for (int i=0; i < ROWS; i++)
   for (int j=0; j < COLS; j++)
      matrix[i][j] = true; //(false if no edge from element i to element j)
```

Then you can iterate over the matrix using the same nested for-loop structure as you used to fill it:

```
for (int i=0; i < ROWS; i++)
   for (int j=0; j < COLS; j++)
      //matrix[i][j] is row i, column j
```

Running time to iterate all the way through any matrix of `n` rows and `m` columns is *O(nm)*

For you, because you're building an adjacency matrix, `ROWS` and `COLS` will be the same value, so you can just use `ROWS` twice. The outer loops iterate over each row, while the inner ones iterate over each column, so it will check edges from node 0 to node 0, node 1, node 2, node 3, etc.

Then it will check edges from node 1 to node 0, node 1, node 2, etc. (Notice how we check for edges to self this way, too)

Because ROWS and COLS are the same value, your run time is actually *O(n<sup>2</sup>)*

You can do better with more conservative methods of representing graphs.

Edit:

Your pseudocode for looking for a sink could be something like the following:

- Create a list that associates an index with a boolean and a count. The index is the element of the matrix, the boolean is a flag to indicate whether the node could be a sink or not, and the count is the number of incoming edges.
- Iterate over the adjacency list, assuming matrix[i][j] == true implies that there is a directed edge from i to j
- If matrix[i][j] == true, then element i is not a sink because it has an outgoing edge, so set its boolean to false
- If matrix[i][j] == true, then increment the number of incoming edges to element j
- After we've iterated over the matrix once, some element of our list might still think it could be a sink (i.e. it had no outgoing edges), so we iterate over the list again to see if those elements with the boolean still set to true have an edge count equal to the number of elements (that is, incoming edges from all other nodes)

I've already shown you how to create and iterate over an adjacency list, now do you think you could look up how to satisfy the requirements of the first bulleted item?

Comment: On it. You are awesome. Ill let you know what questions I come up with.